# SQL lite how to get count of columns grouped by date (day, not day time) and ENUM

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to ask: How can I get from this:

```
ID | DATE | NUMBER| RESULT | TIME| SYNCED
----------------------------------------------------------
1|2014-09-02 15:54:34+0200|800123456|NOT_INTERESTED|10|0
2|2014-09-02 15:56:30+0200|800123456|NO_APPOINTMENT|10|0
3|2014-09-02 16:01:49+0200|800123456|DONE|9|0
4|2014-09-02 16:03:03+0200|800123456|NO_APPOINTMENT|69|0
5|2014-09-02 18:09:34+0200|800123456|NO_APPOINTMENT|3|0
6|2014-09-02 18:54:02+0200|123456789|NO_APPOINTMENT|89|0
7|2014-09-02 18:55:25+0200|123456789|NOT_INTERESTED|89|0
8|2014-09-03 18:36:58+0200|123456789|DONE|185|0
// TABLE STRUCTURE
```

To this:

```
     ID | DATE | NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS| RESULT_DONE | RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED|RESULT_NO_APP| 
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1|2014-09-02|6|1|1|4
    2|2014-09-03|2|1|1|0
```

I tried to do using count and group by time but without right result.

What is right SQLite query for this example?

Edit:

**Added image of original table structure:**

[image]

Comment: date type is varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Taking into account the timezone problem, this query will work, although it will not take timezone into account:

```
SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date, COUNT(m.ID) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'DONE'
AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_DONE',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NOT_INTERESTED' 
AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NO_APPOINTMENT'
AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NO_APP'
FROM dialed_calls m
GROUP BY my_date;
```

**I verified the above in an online SQLLite engine and it seems to do the job.**

Not sure why you include an 'id' column in the desired result? You want to group together potentially several ids (which have the same day), so that's not the right thing to select there.

--- EDIT ---
This works for me in an [online SQLLite environment](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php). Please verify and keep me posted.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE dialed_calls(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,
'date' datetime,
'called_number' VARCHAR(45),
'call_result' VARCHAR(45),
'call_duration' INT,
'synced' BOOL);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(1,'2014-09-02 15:54:34+0200',
'800123456', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(2,'2014-09-02 15:56:30+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(3,'2014-09-02 16:01:49+0200',
'800123456', 'DONE', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(4,'2014-09-02 16:03:03+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 69, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(5,'2014-09-02 18:09:34+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 3, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(6,'2014-09-02 18:54:02+0200',
'123456789', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 89, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(7,'2014-09-02 18:55:25+0200',
'123456789', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 89, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(8,'2014-09-03 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
COMMIT;


SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date, COUNT(m.ID) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'DONE'
AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_DONE',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NOT_INTERESTED' 
AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NO_APPOINTMENT'
AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NO_APP'
FROM dialed_calls m
GROUP BY my_date;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns to me only these values:
|8|0|0|0

I added original table structure into my question.

Comment: Did you run my edited query or perhaps you used the before-edits version (the one with CAST among others)?
I'll verify it with the structure you provided.

Comment: I edited the question. Could you follow the link provided, execute the SQL and verify the results? I tried to replicate your table exactly as well as the data. The results are 2014-09-02|7|1|2|4 
2014-09-03|1|1|0|0 which seems correct (there's only one entry for 3rd September - I believe you have a little mistake in your example calculation)

Comment: Thank you very much, in online service which link you provided is it working fine, but on device is not. I think, that can be caused by timezone which is part of inserted date value, it means that date value is stored like 2014-09-03 18:36:58+0200.

Comment: I found that inserting of new value INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(9,'2014-09-03 18:37:58+0200',
'123456789', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 185, 0);
COMMIT;

Caused situation which i mentioned before.

Comment: Hey! I think I got it - check my updated answer. The only problem is that timezone information is not taken into account. If it's needed, you'd have to find a SQLite function or write your own to convert a DATETIME value to a DATE with timezone considered. That might be a bit of a pain, but it's definitely doable.
Alternatively, we might be overlooking some better way to convert DATETIME to DATE while taking timezone into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by

```
 convert(varchar(10), @date, 111) // 2014/09/03
```

In the conversion to varchar the time related information is stripped off, leaving you with a pure date. If you then want to use this as a DateTime data type once again, just cast it back to DateTime.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for different formatting options if the output is important.